# How to get a filename without using for next

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net

Get a file name without using for next from the directory

```
Dim filefound = Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "1.txt")
For Each inwardfile In filefound
Dim strFilename As String = Path.GetFileName(inwardfile)
Next
```

The above code is working fine, but i dont want to use for loop because i will always get one file at a time not the list of files also i am searching with filename not like "*.txt"

So How to modify the code, Any one can assist.

Comment: Can you clarify?  You **dont** want `*.txt` files?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are actually trying to do... obviously in your example the file name is "1.txt", but you will only loop if the file exists, so perhaps you are looking for something like `Dim fi = New FileInfo("C:\1.txt"): If fi.Exists Then Dim strFilename = fi.Name...`?

Comment: Yes Mark, same way i want to get the same, can you elaborate please

Comment: `GetFiles("C:\", "1.txt")` is only ever going to find one file, so why you loop and what you are really trying to do is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is inconsistent which makes it very unclear. Do you want `a file name` or a collection of them?  If you want `filename not like "*.txt"` then why use "1.txt" for `GetFiles`?

This will answer the title question `How to get a filename without using for next`.  For this, assume a directory full of ".json" files.  Some are named cs###.json (e.g. `cs001.json`) some are named vb###.json and many others.

`Path` would work to allow you to examine parts of the filename, but `DirectoryInfo` will provide access to some of that info via `FileInfo` objects.   This uses `EnumerateFiles` to be able to filter out unwanted files so they are not even returned to your code/array variable.

```
Dim dix As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Temp\Json")
```

Get the json files which DO NOT start with CS.  This will return an array of FileInfo objects in case you need to do further exclusions:

```
Dim jFile = dix.EnumerateFiles.Where(Function(f) f.Extension = ".json" AndAlso
                         f.Name.StartsWith("cs") = False).
                     ToArray()
```

Get the json files which ARE "*1.json" and DO NOT start with "cs".  In this case, the last `Select` method will cause an array of filenames to be returned:

```
Dim jFile = dix.EnumerateFiles.Where(Function(f) f.Extension = ".json" AndAlso
                         f.Name.EndsWith("1.json") AndAlso
                         f.Name.StartsWith("cs") = False).
                     Select(Function(q) q.Name).
                     ToArray()
```

Change the `Select` to 'Function(q) q.FullName` if you want the full path name. These should come close to whatever you are really looking for.